# htaccess - redirect http to https but only for certain domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains pointing to the same place but I only want one of these to redirect all http requests to https.

http://www.thisisme.com should stay as it is

http://thisisme.mydomain.com needs to redirect to https://thisisme.mydomain.com

As an extra rule I need to make sure that http://thisisme.mydomain.com/health_check.php does not redirect.

Here's what I have so far.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Don't redirect /heath_check.php to https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(health_check\.php)$

    #This line needs looking at! Should only redirect any xxx.mydomain.com requests to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # block hidden directories
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    # This makes the url look pretty for codeigniter...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT!

I actually need to do the opposite if the requested domain is not mydomain.com - it needs to redirect to http is https is requested

Answer (score 0):

To exclude `www.thisisme.com` ,put the following condition right bellow `RewriteEngine on` line or above the `http=>https` rule :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?thisisme\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: Rather than specifying which domain I don't want to redirect, in my case it will probably be easier to say the single domain that I do want to redirect to https... there are multiple domains I don't want to redirect. I actual fact, I want to redirect any other domain to http if it's trying on https.

Comment: @Tom Do you have ssl cert for the `otherdomain` ? If not then this isn't possible to redirect it from https to http .

Comment: That's the problem, the other domains are owned by other people and don't have an SSL certificate. Hence I want them to be forced onto http.

Comment: @Tom ssl cert is important as https to http redirect is first checked by `mod-ssl` then `mod-rewrite` executes the rules. Without a valid cert you get a warning and ssl error from the apache ssl module.

Comment: OK, so given that the other domains are out of my control, I'll assume they are making an http request and should be excluded from the redirect... So only redirect if domain is xyz.mydomain.com